# Export excel .xls and .xlsx EPPlus .NET

Tags: .net, export-to-excel, epplus

I have a code, which work perfect when i set extansion of output file like '.xlsx', but when i change it to '.xls', i have window before opening file in MSExcel that file isn't correct (file format isn't correct) and then lots of bad encoding characters (like japanese e.t.c.).

Somebody had this problem? Is there solution?

```
    _currentContext.Response.Clear();
    _currentContext.Response.ClearContent();
    _currentContext.Response.ClearHeaders();
    _currentContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=FileName.xlsx");
    _currentContext.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    _currentContext.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    _currentContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    _currentContext.Response.BinaryWrite(_package.GetAsByteArray());
    _currentContext.Response.Flush();
    _currentContext.Response.End();
```

One moment- when i export it in xls on my local machine, everything works fine. When i try it on remote server- i can export correctly only into xlsx extansion.

Answer (score 4):

That happens because AFAIK EPPlus can only export XLSX (OpenXML-Format Excel 2007 and up)... whils XLS is the old binary Excel-Formt thus Excel does say correctly that something is wrong with the format...

EDIT - as to possible MIME-types try these:

```
application/vnd.ms-excel
application/x-msexcel
application/ms-excel
application/msexcel
application/x-excel
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

Comment: One moment- when i export it in xls on my local machine, everything works fine. When i try it on remote server- i can export correctly only into xlsx extansion.

Answer (score 0):

it prompts Incorrect file extension. but although .xls is correct Extension, dont worry click YES.
Your file open smoothly without data Damage.

```
//Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.ContentType = "application/x-msexcel";
```